# Why am i getting these random timeout errors on mysql database being accessed directly

Tags: mysql, tomcat, mysql-connector

I have a Tomcat and Mysql installed on the same machine, its not been recently updated so we are using Tomcat 7.0.31 and MySql 5.0.95 on Linux.

When a user makes a purchase, its processed by Paypal and then they contact our server and we create the license and store it in the database, but unfortunately it doesn't always work giving errors such as:

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 44,533,707
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   44,533,707 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured
>   value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or
>   testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing
>   the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the
>   Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this
>   problem.

But I dont think MySql is down since I have never ever had a problem connecting to it, the errors occur randomly about 5% of the time.

Mysql contains two db instances and in my web.xml file I have

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/jaikoz</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection2</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/songkong</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and in context.xml (I have changed username and password) I have

```
<Context path="/store" privileged="true">
    <Resource name="jdbc/jaikoz" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="-1" maxIdle="-1" maxWait="10000"
              username="usrnm" password="pwd" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jaikoz?autoReconnect=true"/>
    <Resource name="jdbc/songkong" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="-1" maxIdle="-1" maxWait="10000"
              username="usernm" password="pwd" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/songkong?autoReconnect=true"/>
</Context>
```

Also this configuration is from my *Store* web application, I also a have a *jaikoz* and a *songkong* web application both of these define one of the connections. I had to introduce 'store' since payment provider required a single url to send all successful payments (be it from songkong or jaikoz)

I wonder if having two database connections is breaking things or having two applications define the same connection is breaking things  since I don't think i had such a problem when I only the jaikoz application.

The errors say I could use AutorReconnect=true, but I am already doing that.

Ran Show Process List as suggested and got the following:

```
mysql> show processlist
    -> ;
+--------+------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+------------------+
| Id     | User | Host            | db       | Command | Time  | State | Info             |
+--------+------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+------------------+
| 127681 | paul | localhost:40360 | jaikoz   | Sleep   |     5 |       | NULL             |
| 127682 | paul | localhost:40361 | jaikoz   | Sleep   |     7 |       | NULL             |
| 127683 | paul | localhost:40362 | jaikoz   | Sleep   |    11 |       | NULL             |
| 127684 | paul | localhost:40363 | jaikoz   | Sleep   |     2 |       | NULL             |
| 127685 | paul | localhost:40364 | jaikoz   | Sleep   |    17 |       | NULL             |
| 127754 | paul | localhost:40664 | jaikoz   | Sleep   |    20 |       | NULL             |
| 127755 | paul | localhost:40665 | jaikoz   | Sleep   |     8 |       | NULL             |
| 127756 | paul | localhost:40666 | jaikoz   | Sleep   |    25 |       | NULL             |
| 128444 | paul | localhost:41250 | jaikoz   | Sleep   |    14 |       | NULL             |
| 128445 | paul | localhost:41251 | jaikoz   | Sleep   |    10 |       | NULL             |
| 134807 | paul | localhost:56829 | jaikoz   | Sleep   |   226 |       | NULL             |
| 134849 | paul | localhost:38795 | songkong | Sleep   |   475 |       | NULL             |
| 143552 | paul | localhost:35811 | jaikoz   | Sleep   | 19338 |       | NULL             |
| 145211 | paul | localhost       | jaikoz   | Query   |     0 | NULL  | show processlist |
+--------+------+-----------------+----------+---------+-------+-------+------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Maybe shoud not be so many Jaikoz processes ?

How do i resolve this ?

**Edited**

Speaking to someone else since it is only connections from the Store web application that is failing and that only does anything when a purchase is made which is currently only a few times a day it sounds like the connection is being timed out by MySql itself without telling the jdbc pool, so when try to use the connection via the pool we get the error.

I added `testWhileIdle="true"` to my context.xml and removed the `autoreconnect=true` hoping this will remove connections from pool before mysql just gives up on them.

Unfortunately still failing sporadically but now giving a slightly different error message

```
JDBC begin transaction failed
```

Comment: Have you checked the MySQL server to see what it is doing and how long queries are taking?  Which app is actually giving the error?

Comment: @SteveSmith good point I dont actually know where the logs are , I didnt install Mysql itself. The errors are occurring in the store application, but the queries are very simple and usually work

Comment: @SteveSmith Ive found /var/log/mysqld.log but I cant open it because only mysql has permission and it wont let me sudo into mysql either

Comment: Can you `sudo cat /var/log/mysqld.log` (or the error log)?  You could also try the sql command `show processlist`.

Comment: @SteveSmith, no 'Sorry, user jthink is not allowed to execute '/bin/cat /var/log/mysqld.log' as root on cl-t038-474cl.privatedns.com'

Comment: @SteveSmith i have added output of show processlist to the question

Comment: The processlist isn't showing any problems, but obviously you need to run it just prior to getting the error.  You probably should turn on the slow query log.  Is it taking >44 seconds for Paypal to respond? I'm not 100% clear on the full process.

Comment: Paypal is irrelevant since the sql triggered by a request from Paypal, and the problem just occurs randomly there is no pattern, I was wondering if I had it configured correctly in Tomcat

Comment: @SteveSmith Speaking to someone else since it is connections from the store application that is failing and that only does anything when a purchase is made which is currently only a few times it sounds like th econnection is timing out and dying. But I was never intentionally  trying to keep  a connection open I assumed my code just got a new connection from a pool connection when it made a request that was released when closed, what do I need to do to get it to create connection as necessary rather than have a requirement to keep a connection alive ?

Comment: Ive added testWhileIdle="true" to my context,xml and remove the autoreconnect=true hoping this will remove connections from pool before mysql just gives up on them, now just time to sit and wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing was that I needed to provide a `validationQuery` in order for the validation done by `testForIdle` to work, since then had no problems.

```
 <Context path="/store" privileged="true">
            <Resource name="jdbc/myapp" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                      maxActive="10" maxIdle="10" 
    testWhileIdle="true" validationQuery="select 1" validationQueryTimeout="5"
                      username="usrnm" password="pwd" 
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" testOnBorrow="true"
                      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp"/>

        </Context>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Turn off connection pooling.
- Turn off auto-reconnect
- Be sure your code catches transaction errors, and replays them if necessary -- especially in the case of deadlocks.

Those tend to be issues relating to integrity of financial transactions.

If those do not clear up the problem, then provide

- Queries per second
- SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';`
- Sample of the transaction (SQL, please, not Java)
- `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

As for the `PROCESSLIST`...

- I see one connection (possibly pooled) that performed some SQL 5 seconds ago.
- I see one connection (possibly pooled) that has not done anything for 19338 seconds ago (over 5 hours).
- I would guess that you have not needed more than 12 *simultaneous* connections in the past 5 hours.
- The list looks "normal".

Comment: thanks Ive already disabled auto-reconnect, turning off connection polling sounds like a good idea worthy of trying but I cant figure how to modify context.xml to actually do this.

Comment: The idea of not using database pooling was a good one and ultimately led me to findng a soluion so ill award you the bounty